# Knowing layout used at runtime

Tags: android, layout

I have two android devices for testing. One is with resolution 480x320 and other is with 800x480. I define different layouts in layout-normal and layout directories. I also tried it with layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi etc different combinations.

Is there a way to know from the log of somewhere that in which layout category a device falls just for debugging purposes. I would like to know layout file from which directory is used at runtime. If not then could someone tell me the right combination of layout directories for two devices with the pre-mentioned resolution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) for instance.

Comment: For knowing the height and width?

Comment: No, `DisplayMetrics#density` will allow you to determine if it's an MDPI device (`DisplayMetrics#density == DisplayMetrics#MEDIUM_DENSITY`) for instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find which layout (from `layout-ldpi`, `layout-mdpi` folder etc...) is used during runtime. You can use the tag attribute on your layout. For example let's say you have defined two layouts for different screens, the one in `layout-mdpi` folder and the other in `layout-hdpi` folder. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Layout defined in layout-mdi folder-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:tag="mdpi"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- View and layouts definition-->
<!LinearLayout>
```

And:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Corresponding Layout defined in layout-hdi folder-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:tag="hdpi"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- View and layouts definition-->
<!LinearLayout>
```

To check which layout is used during runtime, you can use something like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
if(linearLayout.getTag() != null) {

   String screen_density = (String) linearLayout.getTag();
}

if(screen_density.equalsIgnoreCase("mdpi") {
   //layout in layout-mdpi folder is used
} else if(screen_density.equalsIgnoreCase("hdpi") {
   //layout in layout-hdpi folder is used
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension of @Angelo's answer that may work depending how you are using your elements: in each file, if you have the same element that you don't need to manipulate, you can give it a different ID for each layout you define (as opposed to tagging it).

For example, say I don't need to manipulate the base linear layout, I only need to manipulate the views inside it.

Here is my hdpi layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Corresponding Layout defined in layout-hdpi folder-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout-hdpi"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <!-- View and layouts definition-->
</LinearLayout>
```

Heres an mdpi layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Corresponding Layout defined in layout-mdpi folder-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout-mdpi"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <!-- View and layouts definition-->
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my code that decides which layout it is:

```
if ( findViewById(R.id.layout-hdpi) != null ) {
    //we are in hdpi layout
} else if ( findViewById(R.id.layout-mdpi) != null ) {
    //we are in mdpi layout
}
```

The idea is that only one of the ids that you define for that item accross your different files will actually exist, and whichever one does is in the layout that actually loaded. The caveat is that if you actually need to manipulate that item later on, this method makes for a lot of extra work and is probably not ideal. You wouldn't want to use this technique on an item such as an EditText because then you have to check which layout you are in to decide which id to use to get that edit text.