# Multiple Layout in android

Tags: android, android-lazyadapter

I have one query.

I have made different layout for multiple devices.

eg.

layout-sw720dp // for 10 inch tablet
layout-sw600dp // for 7 inch tablet

if the device is 620dp, then android which layout will pick up.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic way to check programmatically which layout a device will pick up at runtime, you can use the workaround from [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442320/1482726).